# Pandas not working: DataFrameGroupBy ; PanelGroupBy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have just upgraded python and I cannot get pandas to run properly, please see below. Nothing appears to work.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py",
>   line 613, in pandas
>       from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import DataFrameGroupBy, \ ImportError: cannot import name 'DataFrameGroupBy' from
>   'pandas.core.groupby.groupby'
>   (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "code/analysis/get_cost_matrix.py", line 23, in 
>       tqdm.pandas() # Gives us nice progress bars   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py",
>   line 616, in pandas
>       from pandas.core.groupby import DataFrameGroupBy, \ ImportError: cannot import name 'PanelGroupBy' from 'pandas.core.groupby'
>   (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/**init**.py)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using an older version of tqdm. Try using a version above tqdm>=4.23.4.

The command using pip would be,

`pip install tqdm --upgrade`

Comment: Looks like an issue with `tqdm` and the latest version of `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `0.25.1` version of pandas. Consider downgrading it to `0.24.0`. 
For more information read [this](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/555#issuecomment-517533229)

`pip install --upgrade pandas==0.24.0`