# Why is tqdm.pandas() not working ? - How to solve the PanelGroupBy import problem

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, tqdm

My
 TQDM  == 4.33.0
   Pandas == 1.0.3
I am facing issue with tqdm's panda support

```
tqdm.pandas()
```

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to run the above code. Is there any compatibility issue . I wanted to use **tqdm's apply function** . Is there any **alternative** ?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py in pandas(tclass, *targs, **tkwargs)
    612             # pandas>=0.23.0
--> 613             from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import DataFrameGroupBy, \
    614                 SeriesGroupBy, GroupBy, PanelGroupBy

ImportError: cannot import name 'DataFrameGroupBy' from 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby' (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-36b8b2d614c9> in <module>
----> 1 tqdm.pandas()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py in pandas(tclass, *targs, **tkwargs)
    614                 SeriesGroupBy, GroupBy, PanelGroupBy
    615         except ImportError:
--> 616             from pandas.core.groupby import DataFrameGroupBy, \
    617                 SeriesGroupBy, GroupBy, PanelGroupBy
    618 

ImportError: cannot import name 'PanelGroupBy' from 'pandas.core.groupby' (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py)
```

Please share any alternative solution (if present)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same error , this was because of version mismatch :
Now it is working fine :
Versions I am using :
pandas                             0.25.3
tqdm                               4.46.0

Try this .
If still not able to figure it out use google colab . It's works most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

This comes due to version mismatch between tqdm and pandas.
Try,

`pip install tqdm --upgrade`

If it still persists, [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403256/pandas-not-working-dataframegroupby-panelgroupby) this.